# Composite Set Question with functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm prepping for a discrete final and I have the following question. Just wanted to get some confirmation that my answers are correct or not:

> Prove or disprove (a) & (b):   X, Y, and Z are sets, and  f: X→Y 
>   and  g: Y → Z  are functions such that the composition g∘ f: X→Z 
>   is one-to-one.  Prove or disprove (a) f  is one-to-one.       (b) g  is one-to-one.

For (a), would it suffice to suppose that if there were $x_1$ and $x_2$ ∈ X, and $x_1$ =/= $x_2$ while f($x_1$) = f($x_2$), this would mean g(f($x_1$)) = g(f($x_2$))- which contradicts the given of  g∘ f being one to one?

For (b), I opted to suppose that there were three elements in X {1,2,3}, four elements in Y {a,b,c,d}, and three elements in Z {@, !, ?}. I then posited that if g(a) = g(b) = @, but no x ∈ X that f(x) = a, then g could not be one-to-one. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument for (a) is fine. Your idea for (b) is correct, and the explanation is clear enough that I can see what you have in mind, but it could be expressed much more clearly, and you don’t need to make $X,Y$, and $Z$ pairwise disjoint.

> Let $X=\{1,2,3\}=Z$, let $Y=\{1,2,3,4\}$, and define $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ as follows: $g(k)=f(k)=k$ for $k=1,2,3$, and $g(4)=3$. Then $g\circ f$ is simply the identity map on $X=Z$, shich is one-to-one, but $g$ clearly is not one-to-one, since $g(4)=3=g(3)$.

Comment: Thank you for helping me clean this up!

Comment: @Chris: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

(a)

Let $x_1, x_2 \in X |x_1 \neq x_2$

$\therefore g(f(x_1)) \neq g(f(x_2)) \therefore f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$

Your idea for (b) is right as far as I can tell--that f is not necessarily surjective and by defn may not cover Y--though you may want to provide a more general proof than giving a direct counterexample.