# Let f be a function from $B$ to $C$ and g be a function from $A$ to $B$, such that $f \circ g$ is one-to-one

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

> Let $f$ be a function from $B$ to $C$ and $g$ be a function from $A$ to $B$, such that $f \circ g$ is one-to-one.
>
> a) Prove that $g$ is one-to-one
>
> b) Prove that if $g$ is onto, then $f$ is one-to-one

I'm needing some help with this problem.  For a, could I assume that $f$ is one-to-one in order to prove that $g$ is one-to-one. Such that:

> Assume $f(w) = f(z) ⇒ w = z$ and $f \circ g$ is $1-1$ where $f \circ g(x) = f \circ g(y)$.
>
> $f(g(x)) = f(g(y))$ from $f \circ g(x) = f \circ g(y)$
>
> and based off $f(w) = f(z) ⇒ w = z$, we can say $g(x) = g(y)$
>
> then $x = y$
>
> therefore g is one-to-one

For part b, this is as far as I understand to go:

> Assume $g$ is onto and $f \circ g$ is one-to-one
>
> Then $g(x) = g(y)$ and $g(w) = g(y)$
>
> $x = y$ and $w = y$

Comment: For a) you can't assume that $f$ is injective.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063983/composite-set-question-with-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) Let $a_1,a_2 \in A$ such that $g(a_1)=g(a_2)$.  We wish to show $a_1=a_2$.

\begin{align}
g(a_1)&=g(a_2) \\
(f\circ g)(a_1)&=(f \circ g)(a_2) \\
a_1&=a_2 \quad(f \circ g\text{ is injective})
\end{align}

(b) Let $b_1,b_2 \in B$ such that $f(b_1)=f(b_2)$.  We wish to show $b_1=b_2$.

Since $g:A\to B$ is surjective, $\exists a_1,a_2\in A$ such that $g(a_1) = b_1$ and $g(a_2) = b_2$.

\begin{align}
f(b_1)&=f(b_2) \\
f(g(a_1))&=f(g(a_2)) \\
(f\circ g)(a_1)&=(f \circ g)(a_2) \\
a_1&=a_2 \quad(f \circ g\text{ is injective}) \\
g(a_1)&=g(a_2) \\
b_1&=b_2
\end{align}